# MySQL results doesnt wants to SORT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I got results from MySQL database loaded with this function.

```
function cpus($made, $model, $freq, $cores, $socket, $class, $order, $ad){


$made=="" ? $made = "IS NOT NULL" : $made = "LIKE '%".$made."%'";
$model=="" ? $model = "IS NOT NULL" : $model = "LIKE '%".$model."%'";
$freq == "" ? $freq = "IS NOT NULL" : $freq = "=".$freq;
$cores == "" ? $cores = "IS NOT NULL" : $cores = "=".$cores;
$socket == "" ? $socket = "IS NOT NULL" : $socket = "LIKE '%".$socket."%'";
$class ==  "" ? $class = "IS NOT NULL" : $class = "LIKE '%".$class."%'";
$order == "" ? $order = "ORDER BY 'released'" : $order = "ORDER BY '".$order."'";
$ad == "a" ? $order .= " ASC" : $order .= " DESC";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cpus` 
        WHERE `made` ".$made." 
        AND `model` ".$model." 
        AND `freq` ".$freq." 
        AND `cores` ".$cores." 
        AND `socket` ".$socket." 
        AND `class` ".$class." 
        ".$order;

$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $mod = $r["model"];
    $mad = $r["made"];
    $fre = $r["freq"];
    $cor = $r["cores"];
    $soc = $r["socket"];
    $cla = $r["class"];
    $phpdate = strtotime( $r["released"] );
    $dat = date( 'F Y', $phpdate );

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '
            <p class="model cpufield">'.linkS("cpus", $mod, cpu_id($mod)).'</p>
            <p class="made cpufield">'.linkD("cpus", $mad).'</p>
            <p class="freq cpufield">'.$fre.' GHz</p>
            <p class="cores cpufield">'.$cor.' cores</p>
            <p class="socket cpufield">'.$soc.'</p>
            <p class="class cpufield">'.$cla.'</p>
            <p class="released cpufield last">'.$dat.'</p>
            ';
    echo '</div>';
}
if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 0){
    echo '<p class="alert">';
    echo "No results!";
    echo '</p>';
}
}
```

Every sql query that was made by this function I ran in phpmyadmin and every single works. But if I run it on the page, it will work until its get to order results form database. It doesnt show any error, but when I set variables for ordering it doesnt work.

Here is a html part:

```
    <div class="table-header">
        <p class="model cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'model'); ?>" class="intext">Model</a></p>
        <p class="made cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'made'); ?>" class="intext">Manufacturer</a></p>
        <p class="freq cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'freq'); ?>" class="intext">Clock</a></p>
        <p class="cores cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'cores'); ?>" class="intext">Cores</a></p>
        <p class="socket cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'socket'); ?>" class="intext">Socket</a></p>
        <p class="class cpufield"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'class'); ?>" class="intext">Class</a></p>
        <p class="released cpufield last"><a href="<?php echo cpu_order(url(),$order,$ad, 'released'); ?>" class="intext">Released</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        <?php cpus($made, $model, $freq, $cores, $socket, $class, $order, $ad); ?>
    </div>
```

**cpu_order** is the function that add/replace order variable order and variable ad in address.

Comment: `ORDER BY 'released'` <= that's a [column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), not a value; so don't treat it as one.

Comment: notice: the `mysql_*`functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Your code will stop working then. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instead.

Comment: tip: always just output your generated `$sql` string to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the ORDER BY column in single quotes, this will ORDER the rows by the static value 'column_name' which is the same for every row.

Either remove the quotes or replace them with backticks:

```
$order == "" ? $order = "ORDER BY released" : $order = "ORDER BY ".$order;
```

OR:

```
$order == "" ? $order = "ORDER BY `released`" : $order = "ORDER BY `".$order."`";
```